# How to add an array value to the middle of an array?

Tags: php

Lets say I have this array:

```
$array = array(1,2,'b','c',5,6,7,8,9.10);
```

Later in the script, I want to add the value 'd' before 'c'. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Comment: @MichelAyres The question that you linked to was posted after this one. I think that makes his a duplicate of mine, not the other way around :P

Comment: The linked question has better answer than this @Citizen

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) as following:

```
array_splice($array, 3, 0, array('d'));
```

Answer (score 2):

See [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Answer (score 0):

or a more self-made approach: Loop array until you see 'd' insert 'c' then 'd' in the next one. Shift all other entries right by one

Answer (score 0):

The Complex answer on Citizen's question is:

```php
$array = array('Hello', 'world!', 'How', 'are', 'You', 'Buddy?');
$element = '-- inserted --';
if (count($array) == 1)
{
    return $string;
}
$middle = ceil(count($array) / 2);
array_splice($array, $middle, 0, $element);
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => world!
    [2] => How
    [3] => -- inserted --
    [4] => are
    [5] => You
    [6] => Buddy?
)
```

So thats what he want.