# How to insert an element in any position in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am with an array like `$x = array(1,2,3,4,5);` i would like to add element 6 in between 3 and 4 and make it like `array(1,2,3,6,4,5);`

how do i make it in that place or first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$x = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$x = array_merge(array_slice($x, 0, 3), array(6), array_slice($x, 3));
print_r($x);
```

Output;

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array_insert($array,$pos,$val);

function array_insert($array,$pos,$val)
{
    $array2 = array_splice($array,$pos);
    $array[] = $val;
    $array = array_merge($array,$array2);

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: `array_insert()` is not pre-defined in PHP. You need to create it yourself.

Comment: This answer is the function definition of `array_insert()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)`($array, $pos, 0, array($val))`.

Comment: `$length` is 0 by default; and this doesn't do what the OP asked for. This will replace the element in `$pos` with `$val`, not insert at `$pos`.

Comment: Take a look at Example #2. A `$length` of 0, though undocumented, causes insertion. I noticed `= 0` in the parameter list too, it must be an artifact.

Comment: This does exactly what KoolKabin asked for, and doesn't replace any elements. But it's unnecessary to place the inserted value into an array. Also, this question seems to me an exact duplicate of this 9-hour-old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/php-array-insert-new-item-in-any-position/3797526#3797526

Comment: @GZipp: It is if you want to insert an array, object or NULL.

Comment: Absolutely true, and since doing it that way makes the operation safer, I retract that part of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

It can by done like this:

```
function array_insert_value(array $array = array(), $value = null, $position = null)
{
    if(empty($position)) 
        return array_merge($array, array($value));
    else 
        return array_merge(
            array_slice($array, 0, $position),
            array($value),
            array_slice($array, $position)
        );    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cam up with this function. I have also included the code I used for testing I hope this helps.

```
function chngNdx($array,$ndex,$val){
    $aCount = count($array);

    for($x=($aCount)-1;$x>=$ndex;$x--){
        $array[($x+1)] = $array[$x];
    }

    $array[$ndex] = $val;

    return $array;
}

$aArray = array();
$aArray[0] = 1;
$aArray[1] = 2;
$aArray[2] = 3;
$aArray[3] = 4;
$aArray[4] = 5;
$ndex =  3;     // # on the index to change 0-#
$val = 6;

print("before: ".print_r($aArray)."<br />");
$aArray = chngNdx($aArray,$ndex,$val);
print("after: ".print_r($aArray)."<br />");
```