# How to add a new item inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

This is a array that i printed out in PHP

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [friend_id] => 1 [name] => parker[email] => parker@gmail.com)[1] => Array ( [friend_id] => 2 [name] => peter [email] => peter@hotmail.com) )
```

Can i know how to use loop in php to add a new item/param inside the array like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [friend_id] => 1 [name] => parker[email] => parker@gmail.com [NEWOBJECT] => newvalue)[1] => Array ( [friend_id] => 2 [name] => peter [email] => peter@hotmail.com [NEWOBJECT] => newvalue) )
```

Comment: use array_push (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to add new item at the end of array

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/php-array-insert-new-item-in-any-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for loop you can just add by this:

```
<?
 $arr =  Array ( [0] => Array ( [friend_id] => 1 [name] => parker[email] => parker@gmail.com)[1] => Array ( [friend_id] => 2 [name] => peter [email] => peter@hotmail.com) );

 $arr[0]['NEWOBJECT'] = 'blablabla';
 $arr[1]['NEWOBJECT'] = 'blablabla';
?>
```

But when you have to do this more than 2 times of course this would help:

```
<?

$arr =  Array ( [0] => Array ( [friend_id] => 1 [name] => parker[email] => parker@gmail.com)[1] => Array ( [friend_id] => 2 [name] => peter [email] => peter@hotmail.com) );

 foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key]['NEWOBJECT'] = 'blablabla';
 }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @sirwilliam I was searching this for hours, But your solution best match my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to iterate over the items and add in the new keys, in the following manner.

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $item['newkey'] = "New Value";
}
```

Note the use of the ampersand(&) operator. This ensures we have a reference to $item and not a copy, meaning changes will affect the original $item.