# how to store data in a variable using elequent in a for loop laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a for loop that i am using a query in it , but when i try to get the data it only shows me the last time that query have been running like below :

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {

            for ($f = 0; $f < count($room_ids); $f++) {

                /****************************************
                 * Looping for the Number of Rooms User Given
                 *****************************************/
                $room_price = RoomPrice::with('Room')
                    ->where('room_id', $room_ids[$f])
                    ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $dates[$i])
                    ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $dates[$i])
                    ->get()->sortBy('created_at');
}
}
```

how can i store $room_price so i can have all the data that every time query runned will be stored in a collection or something . thanks

Comment: Make `$room_price` an array. Right now you are doing `$room_price =` which is assignment and would override the previous value.

Comment: Create an array, store data by calling add item inside the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a new item inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253613/how-to-add-a-new-item-inside-an-array)

Comment: Also, this isn't an efficient way to retrieve data. What is the query trying to do with `from_date` and `to_date`?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes  its like  `->whereDate('from_date', '=', $dates[$i])` without `to_date`

Comment: @YJRB Doesn't like because he has the sign of `<=` and `>=`. I am finding it hard to make sense from that query.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a new collection (outside the loops)

```
$room_prices = collect();
```

Every time you loop and get your $room_price you push it to $room_prices

```
$room_price->push($room_prices);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  .=  to store the data till end the loop. Check below code.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {

```
        for ($f = 0; $f < count($room_ids); $f++) {

            /****************************************
             * Looping for the Number of Rooms User Given
             *****************************************/
            $room_price .= RoomPrice::with('Room')
                ->where('room_id', $room_ids[$f])
                ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $dates[$i])
                ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $dates[$i])
                ->get()->sortBy('created_at');
```

}
}