# Inserting element into the middle of array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to insert new element after specific index of non-asociative array in PHP. This is what I've done as far:

```
public function insertAfter($newElement, $key)
{
    // Get index of given element
    $index = array_search($key, array_keys($array));

    $temp  = array_slice($array, $index + 1, null, TRUE);
    $temp2 = array_slice($array, sizeof($array) - $index, null, TRUE);

    // Insert new element into the array
    $array = array_merge($temp, array($newElement), $temp2);
}
```

However, it doesn't really do what I want...it does some strange things with the array. Could you help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php

Comment: Pass `$array` as a function argument. Otherwise you're slicing nothing. `insertAfter($newElement, $key, $array)`

Comment: $array is attribute, $this->array, sorry I didn't write this, it IS the array with some content

Comment: can you post the result of `print_r($array)` ?

Answer (score 5):

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, $index) 
       + array($newElement)
       + array_slice($array, $index, count($array) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to array_slice should be the offset in the array where the sub array will start. If you're trying to split the array into two, you'd want the first sub array to start at offset `0` and be of size `$index`, and the second sub array to start at offset `$index+1` and be of size `sizeof(array) - index`. To reiterate a comment though, `array_splice` is better suited for your application.