# How to insert a new element in an existing array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array named `$topic_notes` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 214
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => Nice Story
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 215
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 216
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 217
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 218
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 219
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 220
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 221
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 223
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 504
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 225
            [topic_subject_id] => 4
            [topic_notes] => 
        )

)
```

Now I want to make a new key value pair in each internal array present within array `$topic_notes` but I'm not able to do. The code which I've tried is as follows:

```
foreach ($topic_notes as $topic)
  {
    $sql  = "SELECT subject_name FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTS." WHERE subject_id=".$topic['topic_subject_id'];
    $gDb->Query($sql);
    $topic_subject = $gDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);
    $subject_name  = $topic_subject['subject_name'];

    $topic_notes['subject'] = $subject_name;     
  }
```

After executing this code I'm getting following output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 214
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => Nice Story
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 215
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 216
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 217
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 218
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 219
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 220
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 221
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 223
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 504
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [topic_id] => 225
                [topic_subject_id] => 4
                [topic_notes] => 
            )
[subject] => 12 PHYSICS

    )
```

The new key-value pair(i.e. new array element) is getting at last position. Actually I want this element within each(all the 10 elements) array element.

Comment: You're writing to the wrong reference in your `foreach` loop. Instead of `$topic_notes['subject'] = $subject_name;`, use `$topic['subject'] = $subject_name;` and you should be all set, since you're iterating it as `$topic`.  Note: you'll also need to `foreach($topic_notes as &$topic)` to write to the iterator.

Comment: Why not `JOIN` the tables and get all the info you need in one query from the very start?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better just getting this all from the DB in the first query (JOIN), but in case that is not possible, use a reference and then change that:

```
foreach ($topic_notes as &$topic)
  {
    $sql  = "SELECT subject_name FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTS." WHERE subject_id=".$topic['topic_subject_id'];
    $gDb->Query($sql);
    $topic_subject = $gDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);

    $topic['subject'] = $topic_subject['subject_name'];     
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either get the index within your loop and set the value there or just use a reference within your for loop. By default, all items within the for loop are copiesof their original array, so changes made to it's iterated element wont be reflected.

**via index**

```
foreach ($topic_notes as $idx => $topic)
{
    // SNIP
    $topic_notes[$idx]['subject'] = $subject_name;     
}
```

**via reference**

```
foreach ($topic_notes as &$topic)
{
    // SNIP
    $topic['subject'] = $subject_name;     
}
```

In your original example you were also not manipiulating the sub array but the parent array!

Comment: +1 for the reference method, was just typing up the code example for that myself

Comment: Yea, im to slow most of the time here too. Damn speed coders ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($topic_notes as $index => $topic)
  {
    $sql  = "SELECT subject_name FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTS." WHERE subject_id=".$topic['topic_subject_id'];
    $gDb->Query($sql);
    $topic_subject = $gDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);
    $subject_name  = $topic_subject['subject_name'];

    $topic_notes[$index]['subject'] = $subject_name;     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
foreach ($topic_notes as $key => $topic)
  {
    $sql  = "SELECT subject_name FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTS." WHERE subject_id=".$topic['topic_subject_id'];
    $gDb->Query($sql);
    $topic_subject = $gDb->FetchArray(MYSQL_FETCH_SINGLE);
    $subject_name  = $topic_subject['subject_name'];

    $topic_notes[$key]['subject'] = $subject_name;     
  }
```

Aside:
Be careful with that string concatenation - there's a nice SQL injection bug waiting to happen there....