# Merge Two arrays in Specific Order PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays one looks like this:

**$shipping**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( 
         [code] => sub_total 
         [title] => Sub-Total 
         [text] => $1,728.00 
         [value] => 1728 
         [sort_order] => 1 )
```

and the other like this:

**$totals**

```
 [0] => Array ( 
        [code] => tax 
        [title] => Georgia Sales Tax 
        [text] => $120.96 
        [value] => 120.96 
        [sort_order] => 5 ) 
 [1] => Array (    
        [code] => total 
        [title] => Total 
        [text] => $1,848.96 
        [value] => 1848.96 
        [sort_order] => 9 ) 
 [2] => Array ( 
        [code] => free.free 
        [title] => Free Shipping 
        [cost] => 0 
        [tax_class_id] => 0 
        [text] => $0.00 ) )
```

I want to merge the arrays together and using `foreach` display thier `title` and `text` values. However I dont want the array `$shipping` to be at the beginning or at the end, but to look like this:

```
   Sub-Total                $1,728.00
   Free Shipping            $0.00
   Georgia Sales Tax        $120.96
   Total                    $1,848.96
```

anyway this can be done?

EDIT:

I would like my array to be displayed in this order:

```
 [0] => Array ( 
        [code] => tax 
        [title] => Georgia Sales Tax 
        [text] => $120.96 
        [value] => 120.96 
        [sort_order] => 5 )  
 [1] => Array (          // <--- this is where I want the $shipping array
        [code] => free.free 
        [title] => Free Shipping 
        [cost] => 0 
        [tax_class_id] => 0 
        [text] => $0.00 ) )
 [2] => Array (      
         [code] => sub_total 
         [title] => Sub-Total 
         [text] => $1,728.00 
         [value] => 1728 
         [sort_order] => 1 )
 [3] => Array ( 
        [code] => total 
        [title] => Total 
        [text] => $1,848.96 
        [value] => 1848.96 
        [sort_order] => 9 )
```

Comment: You need to better explain your question, I am not following what you are asking for. show what you would like your final array to look like

Comment: I just updated my question: I showed the way I wanted the array to be ordered. thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Comment: Create a custom sort algorithm using `usort`.

Comment: @JCBiggar Your question seems to contradict itself... your shipping array has subtotal info, and your total array has shipping info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.

```
array_splice($totals, 2, 0, $shipping);
```

This will insert the shipping array, into the totals array at the third position, just like in your example of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge()`

```
$newArray = array_merge($totals, $shipping);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming $shipping always has one item

```
$newArray = array_push($totals, $shipping[0])
```