# How to use url rewrite with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to use url rewrite with parameters

*example.com/news.php?id=1* to *example.com/news/1*

And the value of *number* will change dynamically.

Comment: so many related questions to the right.

Comment: @PeeHaa - Is the following question 'too board' or not? - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3797239/3944217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]*)$ /news.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Note that this rule will also match `example.com/news/` and will send that to `example.com/news.php?id=`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many similar questions. But here is how to do it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ news.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

You should have mod_rewrite enabled in your server.

Comment: +1 for a more complete and explained answer. The `/?` is an important addition.

Comment: What Is [NC,L] stands for? Thanks... @user3571366

Comment: nocase / NC perfom case-insensitive matching, 
last / L stop processing rewrite rules after this one
Please accept as the answer if this solved your problem..thanks.