# PHP Array: Need Help to add new row

Tags: php, arrays

i want to add more rows to array if statement is true:
i tried to add with the code below but without any success.

1. how to add this row in the right way?
2. how can i set the order for all the rows that i will add by code?

this is the array:

```
    $pages = array(
        'visit'         => array('url' => ''),
        'dashboard'     => array('url' => 'index.php'),
        'posts'         => array('url' => 'edit.php',           'permission' => 'edit_posts'),
        'pages'         => array('url' => 'edit.php?post_type=page', 'permission' => 'edit_pages'),
        'comments'      => array('url' => 'edit-comments.php',  'permission' => 'edit_posts'),
        'users'         => array('url' => 'users.php',          'permission' => 'list_users'),
    );

    // now here i want to add this row to array if somthing is true...
    if ($page_gallery) {
    $gallery_page_id = $page_gallery->ID;
    $pages['gallery'] => array ('url' => 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit');
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set the order for all the rows"?

Comment: Hi @Ja͢ck, after i add "gallery" to array i dont want that "gallery" will be the last in the array.so i want to change the positions for "gallery".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this use **=** instead of **=>**

```
 $pages['gallery'] = array ('url' => 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit');
```

Comment: Thanks! feel so stupid, because i have tried also only with = but maybe i miss something! and how can i reorder the array? after i add "gallery" to array i dont want that "gallery" will be the last in the array.so i want to change the positions for "gallery".

Comment: can you help me with the second question?

Comment: where do you have to insert gallery?

Comment: this code: $pages['gallery'] = array ('url' => 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit'); will insert the gallery key as the last in the array. so i want to change this position.

Comment: check this post there is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `=>` operator:

```
$pages['gallery'] => array ('url' => 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit');
```

which is not really useful in this context. You should be using a simple assignment (`=`) operator:

```
$pages['gallery'] = array ('url' => 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit');
```

The `=>` operator is used between the key and the value of an array within the `array(...)` context, but you are assigning a value, having already specified the key with your `$pages['gallery']`.

The order of newly assigned array elements defaults to simply putting them at the end of the array. If you need to put them in another order then after you have added all elements to the array then you would use one of the array sorting functions (sort, usort, uasort, uksort, etc.) before you traversed the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding a new array index, you will have to use the assignment statement

```
if ($page_gallery) {
    $gallery_page_id = $page_gallery->ID;
    $pages['gallery'] = array ('url' => 'post.php?post='. $gallery_page_id .'&action=edit');
}
```