# How do I insert a value at start and after every 4th element in an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a following array in PHP :

```
$myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k",
"l", "m", "n", "o"];
```

1. I would like to **insert a new element** (*e.g. 1* after every fourth element in the same array.
2. Also, the array will start with 1.

The output will be:

```
$myTest = [1, "a", "b", "c", "d", 1, "e", "f", "g", "h", 1, "i", "j",
"k", "l", 1, "m", "n", "o"];
```

Note that in the above array, there is a 1 added after every 4th element.

Also, I am not adding the element just once. It is being added repeatedly after every 4th element until the end of the array.

Comment: This question has a different purpose. I am trying to insert an element after every 4th element in the array.

I am not willing to insert an element once. The element is to be inserted repeatedly until the end of the array.

Comment: second answer would be useful

Comment: It is a good answer! But The array also has to start with a "1".

And the question is "not" a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `$i += 4` in the loop signature and unconditionally `++$i` in the loop body.  Just use `$i += 5`. https://3v4l.org/5BQbl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"];
$myTest = [1, "a", "b", "c", "d", 1, "e", "f", "g", "h", 1, "i", "j",
"k", "l", 1, "m", "n", "o"];
for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i+=4)
{
    array_splice($myArray, $i, 0, [1]);
    $i++;
}
print_r($myArray);
echo ('<br>'. ($myArray==$myTest));
?>
```

Output:

```
[1, "a", "b", "c", "d", 1, "e", "f", "g", "h", 1, "i", "j",
"k", "l", 1, "m", "n", "o"]
1
```

**EDIT:** Additional requirements

Comment: You might want to use $i+=5 but I did it like that to make it clear the array is bigger.

Comment: Please change the output's inserted element value from "1" to 1. The answer is very good.

Comment: I changed that but PHP doesn't consider because of implicit type conversions in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @fsacer may i know the meaning of [1] in this line array_splice($myArray, $i, 0, [1]);?

Comment: array_splice expects array as replacement http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: actually you could have just 1 instead of [1]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! This does exactly what I want. I have made a function out of this answer and now it is adding my provided values to multiple arrays having lengths up to 1000s of elements. I am just hoping to not see the memory errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the modulo operator associated with the function [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to reach your goal.

E.G:

```
<?php
$myTest= ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"];
$added = 0;
for($i=1;$i<count($myTest);$i++){
   if($i%4 == 0){
      $temp = array(1);
      array_splice($myTest, ($i+$added), 0, $temp );
   }
}
print_r($myTest);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function

```
$myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o"];
$add = array(1);
for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i+=4)
{
    array_splice($myArray, $i, 0, $add);
    $i++;
}
print_r($myArray);
```