# php array push element at an index and move the previous element

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array. I want to push an element at index 3 and at the same time move the previous element to next. **Please read first its not array_splice() work**

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "One_test"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "Two_test"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "Three_test"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "Four_test"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "Five_test"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "Six_test"
}
```

So my desired output is

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "One_test"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "Two_test"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "Three_test"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "Six_test"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "Four_test"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "Five_test"
}
```

So notice I need replace `3rd` indexed element with `5th` indexed element and then **move previously `3rd` indexed element into next**. Finally the pushed element (5th) to remove

Any Idea?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar please read first. I have different requirement

Comment: I checked it fully and perfectly. It works.

Comment: You have `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'` and you wanna put in `'x'`, and you get this: `a b c x d e` right?

Comment: Try it out, and if it didn't work, I am happy to reopen the question.

Comment: Oh okay... I just had a better view. You can do it using `pop()`. Lemme reopen. Sorry for that.

Comment: can you show the code and output? I have tried several times `array_splice()` and not work

Comment: Check the below answer.

Comment: `array_pop()` will not work. Please ready last two lines carefully again. and the output you are telling is not my requirements

Comment: I gave your a demo down. See if that's what you are expecting. Some idiot voted it down as well.

Comment: How can you have `string(1) "One_test"`, as `"One_test"` is not a string of `1` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from the dupe: [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239)

I would do a `array_pop()` and `array_slice()`on the array:

```
$original = array( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' );
$new_one = array_pop($original);

array_splice( $original, 3, 0, $new_one );
```

**My Solution**

So before:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "One_test"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Two_test"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "Three_test"
  [3]=>
  string(9) "Four_test"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Five_test"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "Six_test"
}
```

And After:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "One_test"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Two_test"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "Three_test"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Six_test"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "Four_test"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "Five_test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method takes your array, the index of the item you want to move, and the index at which you want to push the item to.

```
function moveArrayItem($array, $currentPosition, $newPosition){

    //get value of index you want to move
    $val = array($array[$currentPosition]);

    //remove item from array
    $array = array_diff($array, $val);

    //push item into new position
    array_splice($array,$newPosition,0,$val);

    return $array;
}
```

Example of use:

```
$a = array("first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth");

$newArray = moveArrayItem($a, 5, 3);
```