# Generate all possibilities with dot

Tags: php, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm in PHP to make output of all possibilities with dot. produces we can put do in any place of word but repeated two dots after each other is now allowed. for example Shaghayegh 
output like below:

```
S.haghayegh
Sh.aghayegh
Shag.hayegh
Sh.agha.ye.gh
```

output that is not allowed:

```
s..haghayegh (repeat dots right after each other)
.shaghayegh (put dots at first of word)
shaghayegh. (put dots at end of word)
```

Comment: You will probably have to code it yourself. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center.

Comment: This would be very easy!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791679/php-array-push-element-at-an-index-and-move-the-previous-element/36792040#36792040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791679/php-array-push-element-at-an-index-and-move-the-previous-element/36792040#36792040) of mine, and I have solved:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    $var = "Shaghayegh";
    for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($var); $i++) {
        $avar = str_split($var);
        array_splice($avar, $i, 0, array("."));
        echo "$i: " . implode("", $avar) . "\n";
    }
?>
```

The output will be:

```
1: S.haghayegh
2: Sh.aghayegh
3: Sha.ghayegh
4: Shag.hayegh
5: Shagh.ayegh
6: Shagha.yegh
7: Shaghay.egh
8: Shaghaye.gh
9: Shaghayeg.h
```

If I change it to `Praveen`, it gives:

```
1: P.raveen
2: Pr.aveen
3: Pra.veen
4: Prav.een
5: Prave.en
6: Pravee.n
```

Comment: Hi sorry it's not my answer! I need to include below output too: S.h.a.g.hayegh , S.hagh.ayegh , S.ha.ghaye.gh , randomly put dots on each place

Comment: @user3221719 What inclusion?

Comment: Sorry Enter doesn't work in comments ,  i edited last comments and thank you for your cooperation

Comment: @user3221719 Definitely. Ask a new question and link the new question here... `:)`

Comment: @user3221719 Let me know once you have posted a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838550/generate-dots-between-characters-with-all-possibilities  thanks