# Generate dots between characters with all possibilities

Tags: php, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm in PHP to make output of all possibilities with dot. produces we can put do in any place of word but repeated two dots after each other is now allowed. for example "note" output like below:

```
note
n.ote
n.o.te
n.o.t.e
no.t.e
not.e
n.ot.e
....
```

and also below output is wrong:

```
n..ote (repeat dots right after each other)
.note (put dots at first of word)
note. (put dots at end of word)
```

Comment: Is there a maximum number of dots per name?

Comment: No I need all possibilities as output but must be validated that two dots not placed behind each other

Comment: So the max dots would be like length of the string - 1. This is a clue. :)

Comment: You might need permutation and combination for this.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive way:

```
Put current char of source in the result string
if current char is the last one
     output result
else
     call recursive function with the next char index
     add dot to result and call recursive function with the next char index
```

Iterative way:

There are `2^(Len-1)` combinations with dots, where Len i word length.
Make a loop for `k = 0..2^(Len-1) - 1` and for every k insert dots in those places, where binary representation of k contains `1`s (k=2 = binary 010 = > `po.le`)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution eventually by helpful guidance of https://stackoverflow.com/users/844416/mbo:

```
function stringInsert($str,$insertstr,$pos){
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos) . $insertstr . substr($str, $pos);
    return $str;
}

function generate($var="note",$i=0){
    $length = strlen($var);

    while ($i+1 < $length) {
        $i++;
        $new = stringInsert($var,'.',$i);
        echo $new;
        generate($new,$i+1);

    }
}


generate('shaghayegh');
```

for example for keyword "note" generated 7 strings

for keyword "shaghayegh" generated 511 strings