# All possible combination of dots between characters of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a list that represents all possibilities of strings where a dot is added in between the characters.

example:

```
test
t.est
te.st
tes.t
t.e.st
t.es.t
t.e.st
```

and so on...

No dots at the beginning or the end are allowed.

I have searched and found a [solution suited for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838550/generate-dots-between-characters-with-all-possibilities), but when transforming this into JavaScript, I got a "too much recursion" error...

Comment: You omitted `t.e.s.t` as a possible output value.  Is this by accident, or is there a reason for this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just stopped at a random point in time with adding possibilities, not being aware that only t.e.s.t was missing :-)

Comment: @PraveenKumarMekala how would that help with *generating* items with dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just transformed from the mentioned `php` solution

```js
function stringInsert($str, $insertstr, $pos) {
  $str = $str.substr(0, $pos) + $insertstr + $str.substr($pos);
  return $str;
}


function generate($var = "note", $i = 0) {
  let $length = $var.length;

  while ($i + 1 < $length) {
    $i++;
    let $new = stringInsert($var, '.', $i);
    console.log($new);
    generate($new, $i + 1);
  }
}

generate('shaghayegh')
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work correctly, none of the first 4 letters ever have a dot between them.

Comment: @phuzi I think that's just the console limiting the total number of results.

Comment: ok, my bad, I removed the $i = 0 from the function and just called it again with generate($new) which was causing the issue...