# Insert variable within the array search php

Tags: php

how to insert a variable within the search array?

something like that

```
<?php
$imagename = ' forest ';
?>

<?php
$myImageslist = array (
'city.png'
'forest.png'
'fruit.png '
'Color.png'
);

shuffle ($myImagesList);

if (($key = array_search ("$imagename.png" $myImagesList))! == false) {
     array_splice ($myImagesList, $ key, 1);

       ?>
```

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Variables are not parsed in single quotes; Also what exactly do you want to insert? (btw: spaces after your dollar sign won't work)

Comment: Are the extra spaces in your real code? `' forest '` will not equal `'forest'`.

Comment: why have you given spaces between $ and variable names?

Comment: what you want to achieve using above code?

Comment: → http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: BTW, I think what you really want is [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter), not a search + splice.

Comment: Repeat question, please use SO's search feature before posting new questions. Make it easy on the next person. TIA

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I misunderstood the question, but it looks like you're asking about how to have the first parameter of array_search() be variable in nature. PHP's string concatenation operator is the dot (.). As such, you should be able to do the following:

```
[...]

if(($key = array_search($imagename . '.png', $myImagesList)) !== false) {
    array_splice($myImagesList, $key, 1);

[...]
```

Comment: Please set the question as answered. :)