# How to cut array into two

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to separate an array into two separate arrays. For example, if I have an array like this

```
Array([0]=>Hello[1]=>I'm[2]=>Cam)
```

I want to split it into two arrays and add another string

```
Array1([0]=>Hello[1]=>There,)
Array2([0]=>I'm[1]=>Cam)
```

Then finally add the two together

```
Array([0]=>Hello[1]=>There,[2]=>I'm[3]=>Cam)
```

What would be the simplest way to do this?
I know I can use array merge to put the two together but I don't know how to separate them at a certain point.

I'm also doing this on a large file that will be constantly getting bigger, so I cant use array_chunk()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your end result goal, I think a shorter method to get your desired response is to use `array_splice` which lets you insert into a middle of an array....

```
$arrayVarOriginal = array('Hello', 'Im', 'Cam');
$arrayVarExtra = array('There');
array_splice($arrayVarOriginal, 1, 0, $arrayVarExtra);
```

This should send you back `Array([0]=>Hello[1]=>There,[2]=>Im[3]=>Cam)` like you wanted!

The above avoids having to split up the array.

**HOWEVER**

If you did want to do it the hard way, here is how you would...

```
$arrayVarOriginal = array('Hello', 'Im', 'Cam');
$array1stPart = array(arrayVarOriginal[0], 'There');
$array2ndPart = array_shift($array1stPart);
$finalArray = array_merge($array1stPart, $array2ndPart);
```

How? `array_shift` removes the first item from any array, so that how we get `$array2ndPart`.... and `$array1stPart` is even easier as we can just manually build up a brand new array and take the first item from `$arrayVarOriginal` which is at position 0 and add 'There' in as our own new position 1.

Hope that helps :)

`array_shift`, `array_splice`, and `array_merge` are what you need to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your question, here step-by-step to get what you want for your final output.

1) Split Array

```
$arr = array('Hello', 'I\'m', 'Cam');
$slice = count($arr) - 1;

$arr1 = array_slice($arr, 0, -$slice);
$arr2 = array_slice($arr,1);
```

so, you get two new array here `$arr1` and `$arr2`

2) Add new string

```
$arr1[] = "There";
```

3) Finally, combine the array

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2)
```

Here sample output when you `print_r` the `$arr`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => There
    [2] => I'm
    [3] => Cam
)
```

Comment: This would fail to insert into the first position correctly if the original array was ever of variable length -- for instance array('Hello', 'I\'m', 'James', 'Cameron'); --- now the end result would be Hello/There/Im/James instead of Hello/There/Im/James/Cameron --- the answer I provided above, both solutions function with variable length arrays

Comment: i just give solution base on the question. but thanks @mrmrw. see the edit answer. Now it should accept any length of array

Comment: Nice work! I was presuming it could be of variable lengths otherwise the OP could just make a new variable manually if it was always same lengh... i.e. $newArray=array($originalArray[0], 'There', $originalArray[1], $originalArray[2], $originalArray[3]);

Answer (score 0):

array_slice second parameter is position where you want split. So you can do this dynamically by count the array length.

```
$string = array("Hello","I'm","Cam");

$firstArray = array_slice($string ,0,1);
array_push($firstArray,"There,");
$secondArray =  array_slice($string ,1,2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($firstArray);


echo "==========="."<pre>";
print_r($secondArray);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_merge($firstArray,$secondArray));

//out put
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => There,
)
===========

Array
(
    [0] => I'm
    [1] => Cam
)

Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => There,
    [2] => I'm
    [3] => Cam
)
```

Hope it will be worked for your requirement. If not or you need more specify regarding this you can clarify your need.