# PHP MySQL array_pad() on a multidimensional array to display values inside html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I can't get this to work, I'm missing the last step...
***1) query the database:***

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id_fattura, ROUND(valore_linea * quantita_linea, 2) AS quota, data_inizio, WEEK(data_inizio, 3) AS settimana, id_cliente, cod_servizio
  FROM tbl_linee_fattura_el
) tbl_fe
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT id_cliente, CONCAT(cognome_cliente,' ', nome_cliente) AS nome
  FROM tbl_clienti
) tbl_cl
ON tbl_fe.id_cliente = tbl_cl.id_cliente
WHERE cod_servizio = '01200'
AND data_inizio BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-09-30'
GROUP BY settimana, nome
ORDER BY settimana, nome  ASC
```

***2) PHP code:***

```php
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$all_result = $stmt->fetchAll();
//print_r($all_result);
$total_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

I get this:

```mysql
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quota] => 65.00
            [settimana] => 25
            [nome] => John Wayne
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quota] => 65.00
            [settimana] => 25
            [nome] => Clint Eastwood
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quota] => 65.00
            [settimana] => 25
            [nome] => Charls Bronson
        )

        /*lot of other arrays,  I left here only the relevant keys and values for the example.
         *'quota' is a payment, 
         *'settimana' is week of the year (corresponding to date)
         *'nome' is a customer */

)
```

***the next step:***
i found this function on stackoverflow (unfortunally I did not bookmark the page, i will update here If Icatch that page again)

```php
<?php
function group_by($key, $data) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($data as $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){
            $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
        }else{
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$all_result = group_by('nome', $all_result);
?>
```

and I get this:

```mysql
Array
(
    [John Wayne] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 25
                    [quota] => 10.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 26
                    [quota] => 21.00
                )

        )

    [Clint Eastwood] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 26
                    [quota] => 22.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 27
                    [quota] => 23.00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 28
                    [quota] => 24.00
                )

        )

    [Charls Bronson] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 26
                    [quota] => 22.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [settimana] => 28
                    [quota] => 23.00
                )

        )

)
```

***other step: build html table***

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Week 25</th>
      <th>Week 26</th>
      <th>Week 27</th>
      <th>Week 28</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
```

```php
<?php 
$keys = array_keys($all_result);

for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$keys[$i]."</td>";

  $k = array(
    'settimana' => '',
    'quota' => ''
  );

  // need array_pad to avoid empty cells in the tables and php warnings 

  $all_pad = array_pad($all_result[$keys[$i]], 4, $k);

  foreach($all_pad as $row) {
      echo "<td>" . $row['quota'] . "</td>";
    }
  echo "</tr>";

}
?>
```

```html
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***the final result:***
[image: The final table]

As you can see results are displayed in the wrong columns:
**John Wayne** it's ok
**Clint Eastwood** values should be displayed in columns week 26, week 27 and week 28
**Charles Bronson** first value it's ok, second value shoul be in column week 28
(I put the right position inside the red baloons, W25, W26 and so on...).
**How can I display the values at the right place?**
A better MySQL `query()`?
A better `array_pad()` function?
A better `foreach()` loop?

***UPDATE***
I found this thread: [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

so, this is the code:

```php
$keys = array_keys($all_result);
// this is the same function used to group by name, now group by weeks to get all the weeks numbers
$week = group_by('week', $all_result);
$weeks = array_keys($week);

for($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$keys[$i]."</td>";

  foreach ($weeks as  $k) {
    if ( find_key_value($all_result[$keys[$i]], 'week', $k) !== true ) {
      $pad = array(
        'week' => $k,
        'quota' => '',
      );
      // the code to insert arrays
      array_splice( $all_result[$keys[$i]], $i - 1, 0, array($pad) );
      // unfortunally (don't know why...) the first two arrays doesn't go in the right place, so I had to use this other code
      array_multisort(array_column($all_result[$keys[$i]], 'week'), SORT_ASC, $all_result[$keys[$i]]);
    }
  }

  foreach($all_result[$keys[$i]] as $row) {
    echo "<td>" . $row['quota'] . "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

***the final result:***
[image]

Comment: The problem is the foreach. since you cannot use it to take the week datapoint into account to print the quota out to the right table cell. Array_pad is not particularly helpful here, since it adds elements to the end of the array only.

Comment: @Shadow without ```array_pad() ``` empty cells will not be printed in the table (you will have empty spaces without cell borders), I thought there could be a way tu put empty arrays (padded) in place of the missing weeks in each array and than have the values in the right column...

Comment: That's only true if you use foreach. The whole point is that either you should not use foreach, just for; or you need to insert the empty elements into your array at the right places, not just simply at the end.

Comment: Since you would have to loop through your array to insert the empty elements at the right places, it is easier to do a simple for loop.