# How to concatenate two columns in a csv file in php?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, fgetcsv, fputcsv

I have a csv file like this:
[image]

I would like to concatenate the values of the style_color columns in this csv file. To have for example SCJEG4_1014.
I wrote a script, it creates this last column with the header 'Pictures Names' but in each cell I just have "_".

How can I solve my problem?

```
<?php

//uploaded xlsx file recovery
$xlsx="C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/xlsx_files/".date('Y_m_d H-i-s')."_file.xlsx";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mon_fichier"]["tmp_name"],$xlsx);

// Excel in CSV
require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($xlsx);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setDelimiter(";");
$writer->setEnclosure("");
$nomcsv = "C:/wamp64/www/Extract_pictures_Excel/csv/".date('Ymd_His').".csv";
$writer->save($nomcsv);

$delimiter = ";"; 
$csv_data = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        $names_pictures = $data[7].'_'.$data[4];  
        $csv_data[] = $data;
        $row++;      
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$extra_columns = array('Pictures Names' => $names_pictures);
foreach ($csv_data as $i => $data) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $csv_data[$i] = array_merge($data, array_keys($extra_columns));
    } else {
        $csv_data[$i] = $data = array_merge($data, $extra_columns);
    }
}


if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'w')) !== FALSE) {
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only add in the details from the last row ( as you only use the value of `$names_pictures` once).  It would be better (IMHO) to add this value into the data at the point at which you generate the `$csv_data` array...

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
    $data['Pictures Names'] = $data[7] . '_' . $data[4];  
    $csv_data[] = $data;
    $row++;      
}
```

You could then remove the `foreach ($csv_data as $i => $data) {` loop

If you had a different file for the output you could open the output file before the above loop and write the data directly to the output file rather than using `$csv_data`...

```
if (($handle = fopen($nomcsv, 'r')) !== FALSE 
        && ($ohandle = fopen($nomcsvOutput, 'w')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        $data['Pictures Names'] = $data[7] . '_' . $data[4];  
        fputcsv($ohandle, $data, $delimiter);  
    }
    fclose($handle);
    fclose($ohandle);
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your explanations and solving my problem. Do you know if I can for example put this column next to the "description" column instead of at the end? @Nigel Ren

Comment: You can use `array_splice()` to add it into the middle - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php should give more an idea how to do it.

Comment: I just realized something. In my file I have pictures names that are for example 'SOJAD4_' because the color cell is empty. Is it possible to process only the values where there is both the color and the style filled in my csv file?

Comment: Slightly more convoluted than using a few `if` statements, but you could use something like `($data[7] ?? '') . ((!empty($data[4])) ? "_" .$data[4] : '')`

Comment: After '$data['Pictures Names']' ?

Comment: Yes, this will se the value to the various parts of the data (if present).

Comment: It works well but if the $data[4] value is missing, he writes the value of $data[7] alone, I would like that when there is not this value he leaves the cell blank, what should I change in the line?

Comment: Try `(!empty($data[4]) ? ($data[7] ?? '') . "_" .$data[4] : '')`