# sorted array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, sortedlist

in many languages like c#, java, etc, we have sorted array! it mean when we add some element to it, it will add new element in correct index base on sorting method ...
with this algorithm inserting and element is too fast !

but in php as i know, we can just sort array with ksort,sort or something like that and i did't find something like sorted array in php for better performance in managing one array that we want always be sorted!

in my tough if i figure out how ksort works, i could write sorted array myself but i did't find any solution to add item to array by index ...

does anyone know how to implement sorted array in php ? Or
does anyone know how to add element in any index i want?

---

update 1

i need something like this in php : https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-sortedlist

i have huge array (about 2m rows) and i should keep it sorted base on something like price !

for now i sorting it by `ksort` but i cause me huge impact on performance

---

Update 2

i want to create trade matching engine for my crypto currency exchange and for now i using redis as my data entry but when i used in php array as my data entry, performance increase about 250x.

(in redis i can add orders about 3.5k/s)

i tested my code and figured out that `ksrot` take about 83% of my code runtime. now i want to use sorted list as i say for improving my performance. for now i can handle about 930k/s orders(add in array , sort array, iterate top of array) with `ksort`.

Comment: _how to add element in any index i want?_ ...`$arr[45] = "something";`

Comment: What about using heaps from the [SPL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php)? There's an [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splheap.php#93930) in the comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php

Comment: @ADyson `$arr[45] = "something"` it will add `something` to key 45 not index of 45 of array ... for example i want add an element to 2 ! it mean when i use foreach on array, i getting that element in second iteration

Comment: @PtrTon if i use heap for that i just can add element in end of heap ! i want to add my element everywhere i want ! 
`public SplHeap::insert ( mixed $value ) : void`

Comment: @Artier
It's correct but if i has huge array with high add or remove actions , i should split and merge arrays in every delete and add action , it cause huge cpu impact ....

Comment: in c# we have sortedList 
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-sortedlist
i just something like this !

Comment: @MahdiYouseftabar you would have to implement the sorting yourself, such that when you do as I suggested, you would then sort the array (or at least, sort it before outputting). There's nothing built-in in PHP to do exactly as you wish. Maybe someone already made a library for it though, you would have to [search like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+sortedlist).

Comment: @ADyson
all of packages using `sort` method !
for example
https://github.com/malarzm/collections/blob/master/lib/Malarzm/Collections/SortedList.php

i think i should use linked list as data structure and base on that implement this !

Comment: Just thoughts: Have you considered using an 'SQLite' database for this structure? If will be fast as it is in memory. As it uses indexes then it is kept sorted. What I am really saying is that PHP arrays may not be the most appropriate tool for what you are trying to do. All PHP installations come with SQLite as standard as far as I know.

Comment: @RyanVincent dudeeeeeeee !!! using any db (really any you say !) atleast add 250x time to any operation ! i tried redis sorted set but with i got por performance :(

Comment: Databases are extremely efficient at ordering - unless you don't configure the indexes properly

Comment: Would you mind adding some base sample data and sample insert date to your question and what you want to index it on. Also, what rate of access and inserts per second that you require? I haven't benchmarked this before but I am wondering how fast an 'in-memory' SQLite db with prepared queries will perform. This is an excuse to waste a couple of hours and have fun. :) p.s. Have you had a look at 'SQLite? The  communication channel isn't the 'bottleneck' as it isn't a 'server'.

Comment: @ADyson i add more details ... i worked with sqlite and i know, redis is faster than that ....

Comment: I was thinking more of a traditional heavyweight RDBMS really, given the volumes of data you're talking about. Sql Server, Oracle, maybe mySQL could do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found the solution and it was:
Priority Queue in SPL EXT
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php

you can pass your compare method to it and it will store it sorted!

i will create some sort of benchmark for compare using usort and priority queue solution for more accurate decision :)

tnx @PtrTron for suggestion this