# How to duplicate an element in a php array after it current position

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

Hi I was wondering how I could duplicate an element in a php array x times. In such a way that the clones come after the original. If this is your original array.

```
array(
    [0]=>'Clone me please',
    [1]=>'I m here for decoration'
)
```

Resulting in :

```
array(
   [0]=>'Clone me please',
   [1]=>'Clone me please',
   [2]=>'Clone me please',
   [3]=>'I m here for decoration'
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Comment: If you only want to add it to the beginning, you can use [array_unshift()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

Comment: You don't mention the condition for which the first element is "cloned" and the second isn't. But you can use `array_splice` as mentioned by @M.Eriksson above to add a new element in between elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first built a function to loop through the number of times you want to clone your element .. And I made a function that will insert the clone after the desired key ..  It's an amalgamation of two functions I had already built for different purposes ..

```
<?php

$array = array();

$array[0] = 'Clone Me Please';
$array[1] = 'Clone Me Too Please';
$array[2] = 'I am here for decoration';



print_r ( cloneItem(0,$array,3) );
print_r ( cloneItem(1,$array,2) );

function cloneItem($itemKey, $array, $timesToDuplicate){

        $clone_me[0] = $array[$itemKey];

        for ($x = 1; $x <= $timesToDuplicate; $x++){
                $array = array_insert_after($array,$itemKey,$clone_me);
        }

        return $array;
}


function array_insert_after( $array, $key, $new ) {
        $keys = array_keys( $array );
        $index = array_search( $key, $keys );
        $pos = false === $index ? count( $array ) : $index + 1;

        return array_merge( array_slice( $array, 0, $pos ), $new, array_slice( $array, $pos ) );
}
```

Output ..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Clone Me Please
    [1] => Clone Me Please
    [2] => Clone Me Please
    [3] => Clone Me Please
    [4] => Clone Me Too Please
    [5] => I am here for decoration
)
Array
(
    [0] => Clone Me Please
    [1] => Clone Me Too Please
    [2] => Clone Me Too Please
    [3] => Clone Me Too Please
    [4] => I am here for decoration
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function using a few php array functions.

```
function dupeElement(int $position, int $count, array $orig): array {
    
    $mid = array_fill(0, $count, $orig[$position]);
    $end = array_slice($orig, $position + 1);
    array_splice($orig, ++$position);
    
    return array_merge($orig, $mid, $end);
}
```

- [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) is used to create a new array, based on the index location of the element you want to dupe in the original array
- [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is used to get the portion after the element you want to duplicate
- [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) in this function is used to remove the end portion of the array.
- [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) lets you merge numeric arrays in the order you provide them.

The $position param should be the exact numeric index of the item to be duped (0 based).
The $count is the number of duplications you want.  The final array will be $count + 1 of the items (as it includes the original).

For your example, assuming your array was named $a:

```
$a = dupeElement(0, 2, $a);
```