# how to add an item in position 1, for multiple arrays at a time.?

Tags: php, arrays, push, splice

Initially i have an array list like this:

```
[
  [
    "hi",
    "hi",
    "hi",
    "",
    "hi",
    "2021-11-29 00:00:00",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "custom title",
    "new custom",
    "customurl.com",
    "https://wpsn.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/vnech-tee-blue-1.jpg",
    "Custom Description",
    "2022-01-12 00:00:00",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "new title",
    "suvro",
    "www.suvro.com",
    "",
    "new description",
    "2022-01-26 00:00:00",
    "4"
  ]
]
```

I want to add 'custom' at position 1 in each array - something like this:

```
[
  [
    "hi",
    "custom",
    "hi",
    "hi",
    "",
    "hi",
    "2021-11-29 00:00:00",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "custom title",
    "custom",
    "new custom",
    "customurl.com",
    "https://wpsn.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/vnech-tee-blue-1.jpg",
    "Custom Description",
    "2022-01-12 00:00:00",
    "4"
  ],
  [
    "new title",
    "custom",
    "suvro",
    "www.suvro.com",
    "",
    "new description",
    "2022-01-26 00:00:00",
    "4"
  ]
]
```

What is the appropriate way to push this 'custom' in php, without iterating over the arrays?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert new item in array on any position in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797239/insert-new-item-in-array-on-any-position-in-php)

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal no, this was for only one array, but i have multiple array items to insert 'custom' at position 1.

Comment: ...then call it in a loop.

Comment: Also viable for your scenario: https://3v4l.org/1mle5

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    array_splice($data[$key], 1, 0, "custom");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function for that:

```php
$newArray = array_map(function($el) {
    array_splice($el, 1, 0, "custom"); // Insert "custom" at position 1
    return $el;
}, $array); // $array is the array you want to modify
```

Or just a simple foreach:

```php
foreach($array as $index => $el) {
    array_splice($array[$index], 1, 0, "custom");
}
```